Integral of log-concave function on the boundaries of convex sets
Let $g$ be a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be two convex sets with smooth boundaries $\partial B_1, \partial B_2$.
Then do we always have the following inequality of surface integrals?
$$
\frac{\int_{\partial B_1} e^{-g(x)} \mathrm{d}S}{\int_{\partial B_1} \mathrm{d}S}
\ge
\frac{\int_{\partial B_2} e^{-g(x)} \mathrm{d}S}{\int_{\partial B_2} \mathrm{d}S}
.
$$
What if we further assume that $g$ is strongly convex with minimizer inside $B_1$?
